# How do Pathfinder Archetypes with abilities that scale work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

How do Pathfinder Archetypes with abilities that scale work? Like Weapon Champion for example. If you have WC tacked to a Rogue and gains a +1 attack and damage every 3 levels and you multiclass, does the +1 to attack and damage stop till you pick up more levels in rogue? Does it Stack if you choose WC for the Archetype for the class you choose for multi-classing?

Comment: The first sentence of your question doesn't really parse meaningfully, and then you give an example of whatever it is -- can you take another look at what you've written and reconsider the phrasing you've chosen?

Comment: @doppelspooker I'd edit it more, but I think the confusion between archetypes and archetype packages was one of the points central to the confusion in the question.

Comment: Should we edit this question to better line up with its accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weapon champion is an "archetype package", not an archetype.  Archetype packages are a 3rd party concept found only in a line of products released by Rogue Genius Games.  These packages are not compatible with the majority of Pathfinder material, providing no instructions as to how one should handle classes outside of a fairly limited list, nor accounting for archetypes, nor the possibility of multiclassing in general, nor the expected difficulty of entering prestige classes with feature requirements.

> Example: Gord the Rogue is a 3rd level rogue/3rd level slayer with the Weapon Champion package taken for both classes.  Since Slayer isn't a class that Rogue Genius accounted for, the DM has to decide what abilities the slayer loses, and picks slayer talents, advanced talents, sneak attack, and master slayer as one package and track, quarry, swift tracker, slayer's advance, improved quarry, and Survival as a class skill as another.

That said, there are basically two reasonable ways to handle this.  One is to have multiclass same-package advancement progress as if the character had one copy of the package at the total level of classes that took that package and the other is to have each class track its progression separately.  The rules are not well written enough to indicate either choice as preferential.  Tracking a single progression will generally have a more consistent outcome with regards to power, while tracking separately will make many choices less powerful and a couple choices better.

> Example: Gord the Rogue picks the 'light blades' weapon group for his weapon champion package and counts as sixth level for the purpose of determining abilities.  This means he has three weapon advantages and one weapon dominance.  Alternatively, he has two separate weapon champion packages, picking 'light blades' and 'heavy blades', and receiving two advantages and two dominances which will apply to both groups of weapons.

Since you are using these archetype packages, though, and given that they price 'Spellcraft as a class skill, 2 of the ranger’s 6 skill points per level, the ranger’s wild empathy ability, and all the ranger’s spellcasting ability' and ' sneak attack dice gained at 1st, 5th, 9th, 13th, and 17th levels, as well as the trap sense class ability' as features of equal cost, balance is probably not a value criterion in your games.  Absent both mechanical balance and rules fidelity as value criteria and without any other criteria provided, there's not really any way to differentiate between the two preferential interpretations above.

> Example: Instead of +2 to hit and damage, Gord could have chosen the 2/3 spellcasting of the Summoner, Bard, or Inquisitor, or 'Spellcraft as a class skill, 2 of the ranger’s 6 skill points per level, the ranger’s wild empathy ability, and all the ranger’s spellcasting ability'.  These are unquestionably better options in terms of allowing the character to affect the world.  Since that's not a concern, we know that balance isn't a good reason to pick one interpretation of the rules over another, here.  Since the rules don't use the right words for things and don't address the issue of multiclassing at all, we can't pick either of the two interpretations as better on that count.  We've already singled these two interpretations out on the basis of overall Pathfinder design principles, and neither seems to fit better with outside material than the other.  Thus we are unable to decide which interpretation is better.